# Why aren't my posts being saved or published?

Tags: permalinks, database, permissions

I have migrated my site from  a shared hosting provider to my own dedicated server and and am experiencing issues with writing posts.

When I create a new post and press either save or publish, the page reloads with a success message (as expected), however the link doesn't use my normal permalink structure and uses just the ID instead.

The reloaded page also loses all the text I've written including the title, and when I click on the "View Link" on the success message it redirects to a 404 page.

Any ideas what this issue is?

I have disabled all my caching plugins and updated to the latest verion (Version 4.9.4).

Comment: Try resaving your permalink settings

Comment: I did just that, but it hasn’t resolved it

Comment: Are you using Apache for your web server? And can you check there is a `.htaccess` file in the root directory?

Comment: I do have a .htaccess file, it’s setup correctly as W3 total caching has some rules in it... if it didn’t work it usually brings up an error

Comment: I would suggest deleting the file, resave your permalinks, then check again make sure WordPress has generated one and added its rewrite rules